# String Functions are not working in Multer

Tags: node.js, rename, multer

While I tried to rename uploaded image with date, an error is being thrown and it shows "Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined".

I would be happy if anyone could solve the problem. Thanks in advance
I think from Multer an error is thrown and it goes to error handling middleware.

here is my app.js
    const path = require('path');

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const csrf = require('csurf');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const multer = require('multer');

const errorController = require('./controllers/error');
const User = require('./models/user');

const MONGODB_URI =  'mongodb+srv://axxxxn:xxxxxx@cluster0-sm6lw.mongodb.net/sxhxoxxxp';

const app = express();
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MONGODB_URI,
  collection: 'sessions'
});
const csrfProtection = csrf();

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname );
  }
});


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage }).single('image'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
  })
);

app.use(csrfProtection);
app.use(flash());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  next();

});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  //throw new Error('Sync Dummy');
  if (!req.session.user) {
    return next();
  }
  User.findById(req.session.user._id)
    .then(user => {
      //throw new Error('Dummy');
      if(!user){
        return next()
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      next(new Error(err));
    });
});



app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

app.get('/500',  errorController.get500);
app.use(errorController.get404);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).render('500', {
    pageTitle: 'Error 500',
    path: '/500',
    isAuthenticated: req.session.isLoggedIn
  });
});


mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then(result => {
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log('connected');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on windows: `new Date().toISOString()` gives a 'zulu' date, something like
`2020-08-13T10:01:36.688Z`. But `:` is not a valid character in windows filenames. This worked for me:

```
const dateStr = new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-');
cb(null, dateStr + '-' + file.originalname);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to Windows, maybe Windows will be angry if you try to put ":" inside fileName so instead of "toIsoString" you can use "toDateString" like this:

```
cb(null, new Date().toDateString().replace(/\s/g, '_')  + '_' + new Date().toTimeString().replace(/[\s:]/g, '_') + file.originalname);
```

By the way, this is more readable for the user and contains all the information (date and time)

Finally, make sure to replace '\\' to '/' inside file.path when you add imageUrl to db like:

```
{
...,
imageUrl: req.file.path.replace('\\', '/'),
...
}
```